# Why do my app get rejected from App Store due to mismatch in seller and artist name?

Tags: ios, appstore-approval

Dec 7, 2016 at 3:12 AM
From Apple
0. 10.0 BEFORE YOU SUBMIT: PROGRAM LICENSE AGREEMENT
PLA 1.2

The Seller and Artist names associated with your app do not reflect the name, “*** ******” in the app or its metadata, as required by section 1.2 of the Apple Developer Program License Agreement.

Next Steps

Your app must be published under a Seller name and Artist name that reflects the *** ******* brand. If you have developed these apps on behalf of a client, please advise your client to add you to the development team of their Apple Developer account.

The Artist name is the Company name in iTunes Connect. For information on how to address this issue, please contact iTunes Connect Contact Us.

Answer (score 1):

Off-course it's mandatory to add Company or Owner name in App's metadata. Every app is recognise by its owner name to a end user. More-over AppStore suggest more app by the same also.
Even when 2 or more app's name are hardly different, app is recognise by his owner.

Comment: what is the solution please specify .i have already uploaded two apps with no problem .But the third app got rejected ,whether there is a chance for app build issue or any other.

Comment: any luck in finding solution?